# Devise error undefined method `email'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, devise

I have tried tuning my `Devise` views and have replaced email by username. For sure, I have adjusted `initializers/devise.rb` by replacing all the occurences of `:email` by `:username`. I adjusted screens and things were working fine until I tried to delete the field `email` from database.

After having done this, I am still able to login and create accounts as desired by using my new key (username), yet, when trying to update the user, I am getting this error message stating that email method is not defined.

I understand that I am missing a place from where to take a call to this non-existing attribute/method but, I don't know where....

**Some logs:**

```
NoMethodError in Devise::RegistrationsController#update
undefined method `email' for #<User...

Rails.root: /vagrant/src/projectX

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
activemodel (4.0.1) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:439:in `method_missing'
activerecord (4.0.1) lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:155:in `method_missing'
activemodel (4.0.1) lib/active_model/validator.rb:151:in `block in validate'
activemodel (4.0.1) lib/active_model/validator.rb:150:in `each'
activemodel (4.0.1) lib/active_model/validator.rb:150:in `validate'
activerecord (4.0.1) lib/active_record/validations/presence.rb:5:in `validate'
activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:283:in `_callback_before_13'
activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:377:in `_run__265703777__validate__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
```

Comment: Did you check out this guide? https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address
It involves: updating Devise's parameter sanitizer, adding an attr_accessor to your model, modifying devise's authentication keys (config/init/devise.rb), and other steps depending on your setup

Comment: The point is that I deleted the field 'email' from DB. I am missing to adjust something but not sure what and where...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just needed to adjust User model adding the following:

def email_required?
    false
  end

def email_changed?
    false
  end

Comment: still not working for me. :-(

Answer (score 0):

For anyone finding this, I was trying to create a Devise user type that isn't authenticated by email and password.

If you're in the same boat, remove the following from your model:
`:validatable :database_authenticatable`.

These two expect there to be an email and password to validate and authenticate against. Removing them ensures the checks related to either aren't used.